# international travel with dual citizenship and 2 passports

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, filipino-citizens

I am a dual citizen with Philippines and US. My US passport just expired and I am renewing it, no rush. Out of curiosity, I want to know if it is possible to travel with just my Philippine passport. Filipinos need a visa to enter the US, but I am a US citizen. I assume that leaving the US would be no issue, but upon re-entry where would I go for customs, a US citizen with a foreign passport?

DUPLICATE QUESTION FLAG: A similar question has been asked of a US-Canada dual citizenship, but Canadians do not need a visa to enter the US. And I am asking about more than just entry to the US, but also leaving the US, and details as to where I would go for re-entry in US customs.

Comment: Welcome to Travel StackExchange!  These are both good questions, but the answers are going to deal with different aspects of US Law and airline policy.  I would recommend that you edit your question to focus on one of these questions only, and post the other question separately.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie:  Canadian citizens are normally allowed into the USA without visas, while Filipino citizens are not;  so I don't think the advice there is going to be particularly applicable.  In particular, there's a strong chance the airline would not allow the OP to board their return flight without proof that they would be allowed into the country.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert My vote to close was for the fact that it is two disparate reasons rolled into one, with the first one pretty similar to questions already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaving the US would indeed likely be no issue. However you are not going to be able to board the flight to US using your Philippine passport, unless you have a valid US visa in it (for which you're not eligible as US citizen). The airline will ignore your claim of US citizenship - they have no means to verify it - and will refuse you to board the flight.

So once you leave, you have two option for returning into US:

1. Obtain a new US passport in the US Embassy in Manila;
2. Obtain the Canadian or Mexican visa in your Philippine passport, and enter the US overland from those countries.